# Xcode Archive fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode14.3

If your app runs successfully on both a device and an emulator, but fails during the archiving process.

`PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks`

`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

`

Answer (score 2):

You should search for this file in your project.

Pods-[your-project-name]-frameworks.sh (...-frameworks.sh)

**Eg: Pods-sampleApp-frameworks.sh**

And edit this section.

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
  echo "Symlinked..."
  source="$(readlink "${source}")"
fi
```

Changed To:

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
  echo "Symlinked..."
  source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
fi
```

`-f` is added after readlink

[image]

Ref. : https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808

Comment: Ref: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808

Comment: This worked for me - thank you!

Comment: Had this problem after upgrading the push-plugin on cordova. This fixed it. Thanks.